# ng-repeat after ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am frustrated,

I got an `$http` call

```
ApiService.get_request_params("api/endpoint").then(
    function(data) {
        $scope.customers = data
    },
    function(err) {
    }
);
```

`$scope.customers` should bind to an ng-repeat
i can console.log $scope.customers
i can also enter a manually array in $scope.customers and it works perfectly.

I tried `$scope.$apply();` but ofcourse there is the $http $apply in progress.

How do i update the view after the ajax call? Any one!!

Comment: What does your template look like? Any chance you're using one-time-binding?

Comment: Yeah I we would need to see the template, and perhaps the service as well.  [Check this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/C9ANjQvBaiL2ibxMCqGt?p=preview).  Are you sure you are hitting the success block of code?

Comment: @Phil I shared the template in the comment below and no i am not using one - time binding

Comment: @CorySilva yeah i am certain as my console.log is in it

Comment: What does this do if you wrap your $scope.$apply() in a $timeout with 0 time?

Comment: @LouisXIV says apply in progress

Comment: OK, it's beyond my knowledge so. With the $timeout, it should skip to the next tick... Sorry not to help...

Comment: @user3052526 a comment is absolutely **no place for code**. Put it in your question!

Answer (score 1):

When you receive response from http, the response body is in the data object. I need to see your  APIService, but I am betting, that this code will work:

```
ApiService.get_request_params("api/endpoint")
                .then(function(answer) {          
                    $scope.customers = answer.data
                }, function(err) {

                });
```

Comment: You might be right but OP did say *"i can **console.log $scope.customers** i can also enter a manually array in $scope.customers and it works perfectly"*

Comment: That means, the only possible error is mismatch between API response and View... only recommendation to check that console.log(data) is exactly the same, as manually entered array.

Comment: Well then that is a different story

Answer (score 1):

Angular UI Bootstrap's Typeahead does not $watchCollection for changes on an array once it binds.  You have two options, use the async method or simply do not define `$scope.customers` before the `ApiService` call.

For the async method just pass in a function that returns a promise instead of an array.
`uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)"`

Comment: Tried both not solving it. and although i can console.log it is not binding to my view still even if i add {{customers}}